# Python : How to Generate positive number with a given standard deviation and mean within 0-1?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, python

I want to generate a list (or array) of all positive numbers, and all the numbers need to be within 0-1.

I've seen one code,
`numpy.random.normal([mean], [standard deviation], [array size])`.
But it generate both positive an negative numbers.

Any other codes/formula that can solve it?

---

By the way, I found that
`np.random.normal([mean], [STD], [sample size])`, the mean value would be probably incorrect after checking it. For example, if mean = 1.13, STD = 0.339 and size = 4.

Comment: There are two issues here. First: according to which distribution would you like the numbers? Many distributions exist with the same first two moments and positive support. Second, must the mean of the _sample_ be exactly what you specify? I’m confused why you think the numbers you report are “incorrect”.

Answer (score 1):

Beta-distribution is naturally limited to (0, 1) and can be alternatively parametrised by mean and variance. For example:

```python
import numpy as np

def beta2(var, mu=.5, size=1):
  if var >= mu*(1-mu):
    raise ValueError('var must be < mu*(1-mu)')
  nu = mu*(1-mu)/var - 1
  a  = nu*mu
  b  = nu*(1-mu)
  return np.random.beta(a, b, size)
```

See [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Mean_and_variance) for parametrisation and more.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `np.random.rand()`. Pass the length of your array as a parameter to the method. For example `np.random.rand(5)` will result in an array with 5 random numbers in the range of [0,1).

Note: The numbers are drawn following a uniform distribution.